# Как изменить цвет подчеркивания активной вкладки TabHost?

Tags: design, android, java

Здравствуйте. Есть Tabhost с несколькими вкладками. Стандартно активная подчеркивается жирной цветной полосой, неактивные - тонкой полосой того же цвета. Как изменить цвет? Ниже скрин с Tabhost'ом.

https://yadi.sk/i/UXGOcYUwc5Ccw

Comment: TabHost уже устарел давно, не стоит его изучать... Начинайте сразу с фрагментов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После создания TabHost пройтись по вкладкам и заменить бекграунды у вкладок. Также менять их при `mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener()`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(...);
}
```

Comment: > менять их при mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener()

Гм. А селекторы на что? У них есть `state_selected`.